# MongoDB performance with all params defined

Tags: mongodb, collections, database

I am looking to create API for my database calls, I want to make it as dynamic as possible to fit all patterns.
I thought I could do it like this:

```
    function getUsers(query, projection, options, skip, limit, sort, callback){
       db.users.find(query, projection, options).skip(skip).limit(limit).sort(sort).toArray(function (err, res){
           callback(err, res);
       }
    }
```

But these values (skip, limit, sort) will be used not everytime, so I would set them to default 0, -1 and {}, but would it slow down queries anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this instead, and don't worry about the defaults?

```
function getUsers(q, p, o, sk, l, so, c) {
    var cursor = db.users.find(q, p, o);
    if (sk) {
        cursor = cursor.skip(sk);
    }
    if (l) {
        cursor = cursor.limit(limit);
    }
    if (so) {
        cursor = cursor.sort(so);
    }
    return cursor.forEach(function (o) {
            return callback("not sure what to put here", o);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As to actually answer the question about performance the answer is no, if you insert `null` types into the other parameters MongoDB should treat it as the default value and so ignore it, processing the query without those parts.